# SQL Developer Data Modeler - Creating a Physical Model

Tags: database, database-design

The following is a sample logical model created using Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler:

[image: Logical Model]

After engineering the model to a relational model, the resulting model is the following:
[image]

Is the above model considered to be a Physical Model? I believe this is a physical model, but the fact that it's called a relational model is making me have doubts.

Comment: Then why don't you find out what "relational model" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [1keydata](https://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/physical-data-model.html):

> Physical data model represents how the model will be built in the database. A physical database model shows all table structures, including column name, column data type, column constraints, primary key, foreign key, and relationships between tables.

What you have there represents what needs to be implemented in your database.

The relational model is "an approach to managing data using a structure and language consistent with first-order predicate logic" [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)]. In high level both diagrams follow the relational model.

Comment: Seeing as it illustrates all those items in the definition for a Physical Model, is it correct to say that it is a physical model?